# Symfony 2.8 Form Builder isn't working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have been making many Symfony forms within the controller and it is somewhat easier to me. But recently I have created a project in Symfony 2.8 which apparently is the version 2.8.34. However in there when I used the usual form builder it gave me the following error.

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createView" of class
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder".

This is the source which game me the above error.

```
public function testAction(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true))
            ->add('phone', 'text', array('required' => true));

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Home:test.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

}
```

My project does not have any entities as it only sends captured data of this from through an API.

What I am doing wrong? This code worked in Symfony 2.8 other projects but this seems no longer working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the form out of the builder:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true))
        ->add('phone', 'text', array('required' => true))
        ->getForm();
```

In fact `createView` is a method of `Symfony\Component\Form\Form` while in your example `$form` is an instance of `Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder`.